# Вызов поиска в ActionBar с помощью FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.

Хотелось бы сделать так, что бы при нажатии на FloatingActionButton открывался поиск в ActionBar. Пока получилось сделать вызов поиска в ActionBar только с помощью кнопки прямо в нем, SearchItem создается в методе onCreateOptionsMenu с помощью вот такого кода:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Поиск");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}
```

FloatingActionButton создается в методе onCreate, вот код:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.attachToListView(listView);
        fab.setShadow(true);

        ...
```

До меня никак не может дойти, как их связать...

Это вообще реально? Создать какой-то `onClickListener`, который будет открывать `SearchView` находящуюся в `ActionBar`? Я ну очень много гуглил, но так и не нашел ничего похожего... Может есть какие-то другие решения с запуском поиска с помощью `FloatingActionButton`? Хотелось бы реализовать поиск именно через эту кнопку...

Comment: есть [такое решение с поиском, привязанным к FAB](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VebFP9ClYe8) - оно выглядит уместным против нажатия в одном месте, а ввода в другом, но насчет реализации - надо искать или самому делать .

Comment: Вот собственно и [нашлось уже что то похожее по реализации поиска](http://habrahabr.ru/post/260045/) через FAB ( под спойлером "Пример использования FloatingActionButton" )

Comment: Спасибо, я видел последний пример, но хотел сделать не выпадающий SearchView а именно в ActonBar... Ну суть я понял, скорей всего легче будет отказаться от этой идеи)

Answer (score 1):

Может поиск создать не в `onCreateOptionsMenu`, а `onCreate`:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(MainActivity.this);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        actionBar.setCustomView(searchView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    }
});
```

Только цвет текста и иконок в поиске, наверно, вручную надо менять, а то общей теме приложения у меня не соответствует. И кнопка home пропадает, нужно восстановить.